# и пусть (запятая после и)

Tags: запятые, союзы

Часто после «и» не ставится запятая, потому что оно присоединяет к себе другие слова (когда, если и т. п.). И у меня вопрос. А слово «пусть», если оно стоит после «и», обособляется запятой рядом с «и»? Пример: Не он взвалил на себя эту ответственность, и(,) пусть это был и не отец, он имеет право всё знать.

Comment: Второе "и" - лишнее ("бьётся" с первым).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужна запятая.

У вас простое предложение "*пусть это был и не отец*" — с одной стороны отделено запятой, а с другой же тоже надо.

Здесь "пусть" заменяемо на "хотя". В справочниках указано, что c «пусть» (в значении «хотя») — придаточное предложение.